# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

Hi I'm trying to make an Instagram clone with react-redux Firebase react navigation etc.

Now I'm stuck on displaying the Users's information like name and email.
I don't know what's wrong with the code, but I get this error.
[image]

The Profile code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

 function Profile(props) {
     const{ currentUser, posts } = props;
     console.log({ currentUser, posts })
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.containerInfo}>

                <Text> {currentUser.name} </Text>
                <Text> {currentUser.email} </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.containerGallery}>
                <FlatList
                    numColumns={3}
                    horizontal={false}
                    data={posts}
                    renderItem={({item}) => (
                        <Image
                            style={styles.image}
                            source={{uri: item.downloadURL}}
                        />
                    )}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 40,
    },
    containerInfo:{
        margin: 20,
    },
    containerGallery:{
        flex:1,
    },
    image:{
        flex: 1,
        aspectRatio: 1/1
    }
})
const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
    currentUser: store.userState.currentUser,
    posts: store.userState.posts,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Profile);
```

The Login code:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ViewBase, Button, TextInput, View } from 'react-native'
import firebase from 'firebase';

export class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            passwort: '',
           
        }
        
        this.onSignUp = this.onSignUp.bind(this)
    }
    onSignUp(){
        const { email, password, name } = this.state;
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((result) =>{
            console.log(result)
        })
        .catch((error) =>{
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
               
                   <TextInput
                    placeholder="email"
                    onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
                />
                   <TextInput
                    placeholder="password"
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
                />

                <Button
                    onPress={() => this.onSignUp()}
                    title="Sing in"
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default Login
```

The user code:

```
import { USER_STATE_CHANGE, USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE } from "../constants"

const initalState = {
    currentUser: null,
    posts: []
}

export const user = (state = initalState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case USER_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                currentUser: action.currentUser
            }
            case USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: action.posts
            }
            default:
                return state
    }
    
}
```

The register code:

```
import { USER_STATE_CHANGE, USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE } from "../constants"

const initalState = {
    currentUser: null,
    posts: []
}

export const user = (state = initalState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case USER_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                currentUser: action.currentUser
            }
            case USER_POSTS_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: action.posts
            }
            default:
                return state
    }
    
}
```

Index.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { user } from './user'


const Reducers = combineReducers({
    userState: user
})

export default Reducers
```

I really don't know what you all need to see from the code to help me but if I need to update the post with more information please let me know, don't block the post!

THANK YOU

Comment: What does this print ` console.log({ currentUser, posts })`

Comment: `console.log({ currentUser, posts })` gives you the correct value for `currentUser`?

Comment: Your currentUser is probably not fetched correctly and not available in your redux store. Despite fixing you fetch you could make currentUser optional like `{currentUser?.name}` to prevent your app from crashing if user is null.

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito yes it do, I did that just to see if everything is ok, and it's not.

Comment: @PRSHL I did that the error is gone, but I don't get it I log myself in and register random Test emails everything is fine but if I look at the console the currentUser is null. Can you explain why ? And thanks for the help :)

Comment: If you shared all the relevant code we may be able to provide answers to these additional questions. My guess is you aren't waiting for auth success before you navigate to this page and your redux state hasn't updated yet. Also, console logging in the function body isn't an accurate measure of values as a component can be rendered at almost any time if React needs to recompute a DOM diff. For this sort of logging use the `useEffect` hook, it's 1 callback per 1 render to the DOM.

Comment: @DrewReese like I wrote tell me what you need, I have a lot of code and that's my first project and first try. Sorry if am too annoying haha

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the code, I hope this is what you mean.

Comment: What is dispatching the user actions? I'm assuming you've a firebase "onUserChange" function somewhere?

Comment: @DrewReese no, I actually don't have "onUserChange" anywhere. I have USER_STATE_CHANGE if this is what you mean. It's in the User code that I updated.

Comment: So is ***anything*** dispatching the `USER_STATE_CHANGE` action? If not then this is why your `currentUser` remains `null`.

Comment: @DrewReese ok, so what is the best way to do that...?

Comment: Probably some useful information here in [firebase manage users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is connected to the fact that `currentUser` does not have a valid value when component is rendered. You have several ways to solve this:

1. conditional rendering: put a condition on html:

   ```
        <View style={styles.containerInfo}>

            {currentUser && <Text> {currentUser.name} </Text>}
            {currentUser && <Text> {currentUser.email} </Text>}
        </View>
   ```
2. use `?` operator:

   ```
        <View style={styles.containerInfo}>

            <Text> {currentUser?.name} </Text>
            <Text> {currentUser?.email} </Text>
        </View>
   ```

Comment: `currentUser: store.userState.currentUser ?? {},` in `mapStateToProps` might be a little more clean. Normally I'd write a selector function here and return valid state if parts of it are undefined.

Comment: I tried that the error is gone, but it's not displaying any user information. I don't know, maybe I'm not understanding it right. :/

Comment: @chin14 could be related to the fact that `currentUser` does not have a valid value. Have you double checked that `currentUser` comes correctly from firebase?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito Yeah it does, that's why I'm so confused

Comment: @chin14 I saw you updated the question. Let me see if I found something...